# java 7 security update 25 update impact java 1.6 as well

Tags: java, security, java-7, java-web-start, java-6

I have installed java 1.7 security update 25 and after that my jnlp application stopped working even when I use java 1.6 and I am not using java 1.7 anywhere.

So when we update java 1.7 security update 25 does it impact java 1.6 as well.

I am getting the following exception in java console

```
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for : <ip>
.
.
.
.
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### Empty cookie header string
```

Comment: You still have JRE1.6 and JRE1.7 folders in C:\Program Files\Java folder available? JRE1.7 puts itself as a globally default installation, try it in dos console "c:> java -version". Give specific JRE version in JNLP descriptor file to force JRE6 usage, see http://webstartfaq.com/#49 page.

Comment: Or this http://pscode.org/jws/version.html page for better understanding of JNLP syntax.